# Error when Saving PostgreSQL Cloned Table

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I'm facing an issue while working with a cloned table from a PostgreSQL schema. When attempting to make changes like adding new vector layers or deleting a layer and then saving the project (from QGIS), I encounter the following error message:

```
Unable to save project to storage postgresql://postgres:[] &schema=verm23&project=bogen
Unable to insert or update project (project=bogen) in the destination table on the database. Maybe this is due to table permissions (user=postgres). Please contact your database admin.`
```

I've confirmed that the schema modifications match the previous version. What is the cause of this error and how can I resolve it?

Beside, the original table works perfectly, inserting, deleting, or updating project.